# Onde posso encontrar a legislação/regulamento/norma que define o CPF?

Tags: validação

Vejo muito por aí a forma de validar o dígito verificador do CPF.

Vejo também que os números 111.111.111-11, 222.222.222-22, ... são inválidos e devem ser desconsiderados

Sei também que o nono dígito (anti-penúltimo) define qual a região fiscal de um determinado CPF.

No entanto, sei essas coisas olhando a internet e em fontes como a Wikipedia, sem nenhuma referência.

Qual a lei ou norma que regulamenta exatamente como os CPFs devem funcionar? Onde acho a referência exata de como o dígito verificador/dígito de região fiscal?

O mais próximo que eu encontrei é o [Ato Declaratório Cosar / Cotec nº 45, de 30 de dezembro de 1996](http://normas.receita.fazenda.gov.br/sijut2consulta/link.action?visao=anotado&idAto=1893). No entanto ele não dispõe algumas das informações que eu citei serem conhecidas (por exemplo a do nono dígito).

Nota: Acredito que está pergunta faça sentido aqui no StackOverflow pois está relacionada à validação de CPF em sistemas computacionais

Comment: Então, no `somatematica` há o guia de como funciona, mas não há uma referência do porquê funciona assim. O `memoria receita` pode conter a informação, vou dar uma olhada melhor

Comment: A princípio não há nada disso neste link da receita também

Comment: Que eu saiba "o nono dígito (anti-penúltimo) define qual a região fiscal de um determinado CPF" não é mais uma afirmação verdadeira a muitos anos. Creio que o ato declaratório não cita pois já não era uma afirmação verdadeira na época. Note que para a Receita Federal só é válido um CPF que obedeça as regras de validação E que conste como válido no site da Receita (http://receita.economia.gov.br/interface/lista-de-servicos/cadastros/cpf/autenticidade-inscricao-situacao-cadastral-cpf).

Comment: Votei para fechar porque provavelmente a resposta será "*É a lei XYZ*" e acho que não está diretamente ligado a programação. Entendo que a validação faz parte de muitos sistemas, mas isso pode abrir precendente para qualquer pergunta do tipo "*Qual a lei que regulamenta X? Afinal, existem sistemas que usam X*" e a resposta será mais jurídica do que tecnológica (ver mais sobre isso em https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6057/112052)

Comment: Compreendo o voto, @hkotsubo. Em que fórum esse tipo de discussão seria válida? O meu objetivo é criar uma lib de validação de CPF, mas quero ter certeza que ela está em conformidade com a legislação/regulamentação

Comment: Na verdade precisa de 5 votos (ou um voto de moderador) para fechar, então se mais ninguém achar que a pergunta é fora do escopo, ela continua aberta (só achei que seria válido justificar meu voto para ver se mais alguém concorda). De qualquer forma, talvez no [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha) vc tenha mais sorte, já que lá é mais "livre" para este tipo de discussão

Comment: Veja http://www.receita.fazenda.gov.br/publico/Legislacao/atos/AtosConjuntos/AnexoIADEConjuntoCoratCotec0012002.doc